# How could i choose HTML element by inner text?

Tags: html, xpath

For example, I've got structure like that:

```
<div>
  GLaDOS 
  <div>
    is a fictional artificially intelligent computer system 
  </div>
  from the video game series 
  <div>
    Portal
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  from the video game series 
  <div>
    is a fictional artificially intelligent computer system 
  </div>
  123 
  <div>
    Portal
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to choose element which contains "from the video game series" between first and second inner div.
How should xpath expression looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `div` element which contains the text *from the video game series*, you can use the XPath expression `//div[contains(., 'from the video game series')]"`.

To limit that selection to text between the first and second `div` child, try the following: `//div[contains(text()[count(preceding-sibling::div) = 1 and count(following-sibling::div) > 0], 'from the video game series')]`.

Comment: matches ANY div containing 'from the video game series', right? Not only between first and second div (not in selector //div/text()[2] )

Answer (score 0):

This solution is as solid as the source (e.g. if the source'll change, it'll be broken):

```
//text()[contains(., 'from the video game series')][preceding-sibling::div and following-sibling::div]
```

You can test it [here](https://scrapinghub.github.io/xpath-playground/).

Comment: but what if i want to select parent div element which contains this text?(not only text itself)
Something like that:
//div[normalize-space(./text()[2])='is a fictional artificially intelligent computer system']

Comment: matches ANY div containing 'from the video game series', right?
Not only between first and second div (not in selector //div/text()[2]
)

Comment: @Demiteli could you please add a real life example in your original post? If you could do that, maybe we can give you a more precise answer.

Comment: what do u mean 'real life example'? Let's assume, it's research question, about possibility of such xpath expression

Comment: @Demiteli don't these `div`s has id, class, etc. attributes?

Comment: they don't, with attributes it will be another question

Comment: @Demiteli `from the video game series` is in the top `div`, does not matter how you query it.

Comment: oh, i got you, i've added one more div to the question. The problem is:
I want to choose only first div(because it's contains 'from the video game series' between first and second inner div) but your xpath expression will select both div elements

Comment: thank you for answer, last one is closer to truth:) but what about requirement "which contains 'from the video game series'"? This xpath will select '123' text also. Something like that?
//text()[preceding-sibling::div and following-sibling::div and contains(text(), 'is a fictional artificially intelligent computer system')]